# Find $E[X\mid Y]$ for $y<x$

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, conditional-expectation

I'm having a dillemma regarding the integral of a density:
Suppose: $$f_{X,Y}(x,y) = \frac{1}{2}xy\times\textbf{1}_{x\in[0,2]}\times\textbf{1}_{y\in[0,x]}$$

In order to find $E[X\mid Y]$ I know I want to solve the integral: $$\int_{\mathbb{R}}x\frac{f_{X,Y}(x,y)}{f_{Y}(y)}dx$$ And for that I need to find $f_{Y}(y)$.

Since I have this condition where $y\in[0,x]$ I'm not sure how to take that into consideration where I integrate.

When looking for $f_{Y}(y)$ how should I approach? it can either be:

1. $f_{Y}(y)= \int_{y}^{2}{f_{X,Y}}(x',y)dx'$
2. 1. $f_{Y}(y)= \int_{0}^{2}{f_{X,Y}}(x',y)dx'$

If that were the other way around, I'd say with no doubt that:
$$f_{X}(x)= \int_{0}^{x}{f_{X,Y}}(x,y')dy'$$

My intuition says that $x$ can run independently on the interval $[0,2]$ and is not affected by $y$ even though $y$ IS affected by $x$.
Therefore I think integral number 2 is correct, but I'm not $100 \%$ about it.

Comment: What make think you that these two integrals have different values?

Comment: Im trying to figure a 'correct way' to approach this kind of questions in general. Im not sure the answer is different, but I want to know how to look at it the right way

Comment: You need to be careful about what $\int_y^2$ really means.   It is usually not the same as $\int_{[0,2]}$. The general 'correct' answer is always $\int_\mathbb R f_{X,Y}(x', y) dx'$, as it is the definition. But if you factor in this particular $f_{X,Y}$, it reduces to integral 1 (at least for $y\le 2$) and integral 2.

Comment: I see. thank you

Comment: sorry, there is a typo. I meant $\int_y^2$ is usually not the same as $\int_{[y,2]}$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to find $f_{Y}(y)$, you should compute it in this way: $f_{Y}(y)= \int_{\mathbb R}{f_{X,Y}}(x',y)dx'=\int_{\mathbb R}\frac{1}{2}x'y\times\textbf{1}_{x'\in[0,2]}\times\textbf{1}_{y\in[0,x']}=\\
\\ =\int_{[0,2] \cap [y,+\infty]}\frac{1}{2}x'y dx'=\frac 1 2 y \int_{[0,2] \cap [y,+\infty]}x'dx'$

and the last one depends on $y$. If $y \leq 0$ then $[0,2] \cap [y,+\infty]=[0,2]$, if $0 < y < 2$ then $[0,2] \cap [y,+\infty]=[y,2]$ and if $y > 2$ then $[0,2] \cap [y,+\infty]= \emptyset$. The case $y=2$ does not really matter.

Comment: Thank you. So since $y\geq 0$ I AM affected by Y in this intersection. so the integral starts from y.

Comment: @AviP Yes, that is the point.